Возможно ли с помощью traceroute определить, что пользователь использует прокси?
Возможно ли с помощью traceroute определить, что пользователь использует прокси? В частности вот, я подключился к прокси серверу и мы делаем traceroute до google.com

И как мы видим, здесь получается всего 2 прыжка. Если я выключаю прокси и со своего домашнего или мобильного интернета выполняю traceroute, - то получаю около 10 прыжков

Получается, таким образом можно определить сидит пользователь через прокси или нет? Спасибо

Прыжки от кого до кого? На этих скриншотах не очень понятно что вы вообще сделали

Два прыжка — редкость даже в локальной сети, так что есть подозрение, что вы просто не понимаете что смотрите (и я тоже не понимаю, потому что вы не указали, прыжки от кого до кого)

@andreymal понял, извиняюсь. В частности здесь идет запрос до google.com

IP-адрес 100.64.0.18 не является публичным и вообще не относится к интернету (и уж тем более не относится к гуглу), так что вы всё равно явно делаете что-то не так

@andreymal вот если я иду до 8.8.8.8, тоже 2 прыжка, если я подключен к прокси https://i.imgur.com/fzeUYWz.jpg

Значит наверно трассировка через прокси просто врёт по какой-то причине (например, если прокси в принципе не поддерживает трассировку в своём протоколе и в итоге на ваших скриншотах просто бред)

@andreymal а, то есть прокси может не поддерживать трассировку?

@andreymal но вообще это же тоже странно может показаться. Все нормальные провайдеры по идее будут её поддерживать? И тогда мы можем начать как минимум подозревать, что пользователь использует прокси, нет?

Если сторона, которая подозревает вас в использовании прокси, попытается сделать трассировку до «вашего» IP-адреса, то она просто увидит самую обычную трассировку до прокси-сервера с десятком прыжков, ничего интересного. Другое дело, что у неё могут быть какие-нибудь другие поводы заподозрить, что IP-адрес может являться адресом прокси-сервера — например, если IP-адрес принадлежит дата-центру, ведь простые люди обычно не живут в дата-центрах

@andreymal Нет, вот прямо если на моём устройстве и выполнит трассировку до google.com или 8.8.8.8 и увидит вот эту "ахинею" из пары прыжков. В частности, если я нахожусь в приложении сервиса

Прямо на вашем устройстве достаточно зайти в настройки этого устройства и увидеть, что там настроен прокси

@andreymal если я настрою прокси на уровне роутера - уже не получится увидеть. но все еще можно выполнить вот этот traceroute. вот я о чем

@andreymal в прокси ответили вот так: "Из-за технических особенностей реализации нашего ВПН, команды типа tracert/ping, выполняемые вами, будут отображать некорректную информацию, то же самое касается приложении, которые их используют. На это можно не обращать внимание, на анонимность работы это не влияет".

В частности, я имею ввиду, если сервис будет выполнять эту команду traceroute внутри моего приложения, на моем телефоне. На всех Интернетах что я тестировал и друзей просил - около 10 прыжков и все нормально. А как только я включаю какие-нибудь прокси - начинаются приколы с прыжками ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Так тут везде речь про VPN на самом деле? Просто под "прокси" обычно вроде подразумевается "http proxy" и непонятно, какой там может быть traceroute вообще через него. Куда и как прокладывает тоннель VPN - это действительно только самих создателей конкретного VPN нужно пытать.
